# Finding simple min-weight path between two vertices in graph with negative edge weights

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, polynomial-time

Given a weighted graph (negative weights are allowed) and two vertices $u$ and $v$, can we find the simple min-weight path between $u$ and $v$? There can be a negative cycle on the path from $u$ to $v$, but we want to ignore that, and calculate the weight of a simple path between them. Can this be done in polynomial time?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17462

Comment: @Raphael, what are we supposed to do with an on-topic question that has been answered nicely at a brother-site, cstheory?